# display custom product options in product list

Tags: magento, product, php

Is it possible to display custom product options into the list.phtml?
It is a text field, i'm using magento 1.6.1

Greetz,

Fluxxi

Comment: Have you Googled this? There are several hits that look like they could be helpful

Comment: Yes, but I could find anything.

Answer (score 1):

It's not programming feature. Goto Admin -> Catalog -> Attributes -> Manage Attributes then select the attribute that you want to show product page. Then change "Visible on Product View Page on Front-end" properties to "Yes".